# Python hash is not deterministic with sympy objects

Tags: hash, sympy

I am feeding symbolic expressions to a function, and would like to return previously computed results when the set of input arguments has already been treated before. To that purpose, I was thinking of hashing the arguments passed to the function, but this does not work because it seems that `hash` does not produce determistic results when applied to symbolic expressions. For example, the following code prints values that are always different.

```
import sympy as sym
x = sym.symbols('x')
print(hash(x))
```

Is there a way to deterministally hash Sympy symbolic expressions?

Comment: What do you mean by always different? `x = sym.symbols('x'); 
print(hash(x)); print(hash(x));` should bring the same number twice.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but not when I rerun the whole program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into a security feature known as hash randomization.

```
$ cat hash_test.py 
import sympy as sym
x = sym.symbols('x')
print(hash(x))
```

A few runs with this simple example:

```
$ python hash_test.py 
6842375726913792912
$ python hash_test.py 
5041915772945005780
$ python hash_test.py 
-3461975266180802906
```

Run without hash randomization to get the same results:

```
$ PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python hash_test.py 
-2285490307665029553
$ PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python hash_test.py 
-2285490307665029553
$ PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python hash_test.py 
-2285490307665029553
```

Answer (score 1):

From here:
http://docs.sympy.org/latest/python-comparisons.html
https://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-hashable

> Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by
>   default. They all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their
>   hash value is derived from their id().

```
def __hash__(self):
    return id(self)
```

Which I imagine is the reason you are having the different hash, as the instances have a different id.

I hope you can get the comparison you need from the first doc I posted.